# Windows Forms Multiple DataSets

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

Good Day,

I have 2 DataSets in my project, they are identical except 1 is for SQLite and 1 for MSSQL. I am looking for a way to use only one of these datasets in my forms at a time, depending on which connection the client wishes to use.

For example 1 client can choose to use SQLite whereas another client can choose MSSQL.

When searching online I only find ways to change the connection string of a single DataSet. Of course when I change the connection string of the SQLite Dataset to the MSSQL connection string, I get an error.

How can I change the Default DataSet to use in my application depending on what the client chooses?

I honestly have no idea and I have been searching for a long while.

Edit - Is there a way to change the data provider of the dataset? That way it should be possible to change the connection string without getting the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

**EDIT**
[Connection Strings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeFZj.png)

[App.config Connection Strings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKg2Z.png)

**EDIT 2**
[Error when changing connection string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSN5l.png)

Comment: if MSSQL is used use this connection string else if SQLite is used use this string?
Also some code would be appreaciated or at lest the strings so our answars are more comprehendable.

Comment: @DenisSchaf I understand that code would help quite a lot, however I have no code to show. I have literally just set up the DataSets with their respective ConnectionStrings. And As I stated, when I change the connection string of one dataset I get an error. I will however edit my question and try to include more information.

Comment: Don't bother; the db level differences are baked into the TableAdapters. Probably the easiest thing to do is to create interfaces and use a partial to declare the datatables as implementing them so you can treat them consistently

Comment: You could also try putting per DB queries on each TabkeAdapter (add query, specify other connection string) and see if it reuses the columns.. it should but I'm not sure what happens if the types differ

Comment: What you need is the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). There's even a good C# example in there.

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for the response. It seems like there is no easy way to do this haha. I will try your suggestions and check the results.

Comment: @SupertimeDeveloper - There is absolutely easy ways to do this. Separation of concerns with the strategy pattern makes this straight forward.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you for the link. I will read through everything now.

Comment: I think perhaps easiest overall would be to depart from he notion of using SQLite and to use use some small version of SQLS like LocalDB or SQLServer Express instead

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah it makes sense. It makes me think of a state machine in some ways. Maybe it's not, but that's how I understand it haha. But I created a DBContext class which spesifies which Database I'd like to connect to. All the queries in both databases are very similar so I can just execute the same functions for either databases. However this is not very useful (yet) when populating form controls with database values.

Comment: @CaiusJard I just had a look at SQL Server Compact 4.0, but I don't like it very much. I really need one instance to not rely on any server. This is only because some of our client's PC don't have great specs. I feel like a server instance just creates too much "overhead" or whatever for the clients where only one person will work on the system.

Comment: Performance is something you measure, not *feel*, surely? Have you verified the performance is lacking with e.g. LocalDB

Comment: @CaiusJard I definitely agree. And yes we have. I don't mind trying the LocalDB, however I have read that LocalDB is more suited for development purposes and not the best to be used in deployment. I don't know how true this is, this is simply something I have read. Besides, Performance is not my main motivator to implement a SQLite database. Our team is not yet at a standard to maintain SQL databases, thus I need to make sure the database is simple enough at this time for the team to install and maintain on each client's pc while still having the option of using SQL at a later point in time.

Comment: @CaiusJard [Part 2] This might not make much sense, but unfortunately these are the cards I have been dealt and I need to work with it. Thank you for the answers though. I will see what I can do and how I would meet our project's requirements.

Comment: If it's new dev, it would probably simplify your life to use a different data access technology; TableAdapters/DataSets are quite old now and though I have a soft spot for them, I can't help but note that the likes of EFCore really does blow them away for many things. The only reason I carry on using them from time to time is the great integration with windows forms/control binding - it does make that aspect somewhat easier but that EF will work with SQLite/SQLS as a "flick of the switch" like you're trying to do here, out of the box, is something that should be looked at

Comment: In the end, it can all be made to work; it's just working out what the pain point is. With EF I suspect the binding part would be comparably more awkward, with DataSets the multi DB part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the kind of thing I am thinking when it comes to the strategy pattern.

First start with an interface that describes all of the data access that you need to do that is completely database agnostic:

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    DataTable GetPeople();
}
```

Now you can implement concrete examples of how to get that data.

```
public class SQLiteDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public SQLiteDataAccess(string connectionString)
    { }

    public DataTable GetPeople()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");
        dt.Rows.Add("Fred", 40);
        dt.Rows.Add("Barney", 39);
        return dt;
    }
}

public class MSSqlDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public MSSqlDataAccess(string connectionString)
    { }

    public DataTable GetPeople()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");
        dt.Rows.Add("Abbot", 50);
        dt.Rows.Add("Costello", 49);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

There's no limitation to using a database. I could make a file system version.

```
public class FileDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    private readonly string _fileName;

    public FileDataAccess(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public DataTable GetPeople()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(_fileName))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(','));
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Now you can program your UI to use the strategy that you want:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDataAccess da = new SQLiteDataAccess("SQL1");
        //IDataAccess da = new MSSqlDataAccess("MS1");
        //IDataAccess da = new FileDataAccess(@"C:\text.csv");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = da.GetPeople();
    }
}
```

By changing that one line you change where the data is coming from in your app.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation and code provided! This helps a ton!